# It shows me the content of other components behind the JButton that I have clicked on JPanel. What is happening?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

[image]

After clicking the button I get the popup and it also shows me the content on the button.

[image]

This also happens when I put the mouse on the first button and then I put on another the text of the first button is shown in the second.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String action = e.getActionCommand();

        switch (action) {
        case "start_game":
            this.createPanels();
            break;
        case "sel_hero":
            this.selectHero();
            break;
        case "cal_sel":
            this.clickedCancel();
            break;
        case "start":
            this.clickedStart();
            break;
        case "fight":
            this.clickedFight();
            break;
        case "auto":
            this.clickedAuto();
            break;
        ...
        default:
            this.mainPanel();
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is the method that creates the popup.

[image]

```
 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1440, 960);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.selected = null;
        this.enemySelected = null;
        this.gridLayout = new GridLayout(0, 2);
        this.checks = new HashMap<>();
        this.checks.put(0, true);
        this.checks.put(1, true);
        this.checks.put(2, true);

        this.contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1376, 600));

        // load game model
        game = new Game();

        // load welcome page
        this.mainPanel();
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: You need to separate your listeners.  Having a single monolithic listener is asking for trouble as it makes it very difficult to control and troubleshoot.  Ideally you should have an Action for each button (for multiple reason I can go into if needs be) and you create the buttons using the action.

Comment: Do not post images of code.  It’s hard to read, impossible to copy and test, impossible to search, and excludes sight impaired readers.  Instead, edit your question and copy the actual text into a code block in your question.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).